Showing attribute-form with objects of another shapefile in QGIS
QGIS 3.34.6: I have two layers, layer 1 shows different bridges, and layer 2 contains different events at these bridges in different years. Each event is one object in layer 2.
I would like to get an attribute form in the following way: I click on one bridge (layer 1) and I get an attribute form with all events (saved in layer 2), that occurred at the bridge - e.g. within a radius of 10 metres.
Here you see an example of the attribute form I want to have and an example of the map (red: layer 1, green: layer 2)


Of course, I could make a selection query in layer 2, but I would like to have the information of this bridge (and a photo of the bridge) together with the events around this bridge in one attribute form. Does anyone know a possibility?

If you add a bridge_id value to each event, you can use a relation as shown here

thanks for the idea. But I would like to get it without a bridge_id. The events should appear in the list (in the attribute-form) if they are within 10 metres of the bridge - i.e. a selection by position.
